# Delphi 5 need to extend ADODB_TLB interfaces

Tags: delphi, com, ado

This is a question which will likely cause some seasoned developers flashbacks of artillery fire in Foxbase holes dug with ancient equipment...

We have an aging bit of web code that we need to do some low-level database handling on.  We have an COM library we've written to do other handling, like encryption and user authentication, and we've determined the best way to do this is to create a COM interface that extends the existing ADODB_TLB interface, with some added handling.

How it will be used when all is said and done, is to replace some existing calls that look like this:

```
    Set CMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    CMD.ActiveConnection = DB
    CMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    CMD.CommandText = "Country_Code_Get"
    CMD.Parameters.Append CMD.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 4, NULL)       
    Set RS = CMD.Execute()
```

with new code that will look more like this:

```
    Set CMD = Server.CreateObject("MyADODB.Command")
    CMD.ActiveConnection = DB
    CMD.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    CMD.CommandText = "Country_Code_Get"
    CMD.SpecialHandling = "Extra Stuff"
    CMD.Parameters.Append CMD.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, 4, NULL)       
    Set RS = CMD.Execute()
```

The goal is to extend the existing ADODB library to enable our additional handling with a minimal amount of changes required to our large code base.

Is there a way to extend the existing _Command interface to add only our new parameter (and, of course, overriding the necessary Execute function to handle the new parameter appropriately) without needing to effectively duplicate the entire _Command interface?

Comment: It's quite straightforward to modify the implementation section of AdoDB.Pas, as long as you don't change the interface section.  I've done this to work around a couple of oddities.   I don''t know of an easy way to modify the _Command interface, if you mean the COM interface, but you can certainly change how it is called from AdoDB.Pas

Comment: Would this include adding new properties to the class as well?

Comment: Not to the classes declared in AdoDB.Pas's interface, if you want design-time support, because the classes' properties appear in the interface (in more recent Delphi versions you could add property getters and setters using a "class helper" but D5 was 20 years too early for that).  However, there is nothing to stop you creating a unit which declares descendants of the classes in AdoDB and adds whatever properties you want - you'd need to see whether the methods which use them are overridable in AdoDB, of course.

Comment: Calling `CreateObject()` with a different name instantiates a different COM object. So all you would have to do is implement your own COM class with is own CLSID and TLB, and have its default CoClass interface derive from ADO's `Command` interface so you inherit ADO's existing methods and properties. Then you can add whatever you want to your custom class as needed. Internally, your custom class can instantiate ADO's real `Command` object and delegate to it as needed. You are not actually extending ADO itself, you are merely putting a wrapper around it. No need to change the AdoDB units.

Comment: @MartinA I don't think this will work for us because when a workstation issues the Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") call, it is creating an instance of the Command class in the ADODB library that is installed on the webserver, which *isn't* he one I will have overridden (this is for web sites, not an app that is deployed on the machine.)  (Sorry, Remy, this was replying to MartynA's comment, not yours.)

Comment: @Remy, yes, this is what I was attempting to do, but I am getting tangled up in the Type Library GUI and the resulting classes it generates, which are being declared like TMyConnection = class(TASPObject, IMyConnection)

Comment: @Dan: when replying to someone specific, please use the `@<name>` syntax in your comment (as I did in this comment). Not only does it show who you are talking to, but it will also notify that person that a comment was directed at them.

Comment: @Remy: so, would I declare the Parent Interface in the Type Library as "_Command?"  We have an existing Library that we're adding this functionality to, so I've got the COM class, with its own CLSID and TLB declared, just trying to get the meat on the bones.

Comment: @Dan: You have to add a reference to ADO's TypeLibrary to your TypeLibrary's `uses` list.  Then you can set ADO's `_Command` interface as the Parent Interface for your class's interface, yes.

Comment: @Remy, done and done, but now my TLB as added a number of references into my IMyCommandDisp = dispinterface listing, including CommandStream, Dialect, NamedParameters, etc.  Do I create a private property within my class where I store the _Command object, then create wrappers for each of these shells, pointing each one back to the _Command-typed property I created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105192/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-dan).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly, the code snippet in your question will probably use late binding on the Command object. This means it will probably pass through the methods of the [IDispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608.aspx) interface. Have a look at the `TAutoObject` from the `ComObj.pas` unit, it implements `IDispatch` and maps onto type info from the Delphi type system.

So in this case *extending* ADO, I wouldn't bother with ADO_TLB or the type library GUI (except perhaps maybe File > New > Other... and from the ActiveX-tab: "Automation Object") and concentrate on creating an alternative IDispatch implementation, patching any calls you don't override through to an IDispatch pointer of a live instance of an ADO.Command instance. (There's more about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221037.aspx))